# NUnit TestFixtureSetUp runs multiple times?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, nunit

I have a basic Test setup using NUnit 2.6 and Visual NUnit in Visual Studio 2010. My problem is that when I'm running all tests it seems like the FixtureSetup method (which has the TestFixtureSetUpAttribute) is running one time for each of the tests.

I've also tried to put the Init code to the constructor, but it gives the same results.

The tests themselves reports their run time to runtime like 0.003 and 0.032 and so on.

```
    [TestFixture]
    public class MODatabaseTests
    {
        [TestFixtureSetUp]
        public static void FixtureSetup()
        {
           // Perform heavy init (~1.5s)
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestA()
        {
            ...
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestB()
        {
            ...
        }

    }
```

Comment: _it seems like_ -- can you debug (or at least Console.Write) so you're _sure_ it's getting hit multiple times?

Comment: I cant. If I add Console.WriteLine it doesnt show up when running in Visual NUnit.

Comment: How does Visual NUnit report?

Comment: It seems like this is a "Visual NUnit" problem, because if I run this in the NUnit GUI tester it works as intended... That is really odd.

Comment: Visual NUnit reports the run times for the tests to like 0.03, 0.32, 0.082 sec ans so on. But it's definently using more time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add this code, you can confirm your suspicion:

```
    private static bool initialized = false;
    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public static void FixtureSetup()
    {
        if (initialized) Assert.Fail("fixture setup called multiple times");
        initialized = true;
        ...
    }
```

The test runner may calling every test individually instead of treating a TestFixture as a suite of tests.

As an aside, I would avoid `static` in unit tests because if you have any static variables, their state would be carried from each run (though the fixture kind of wants this) and you lose the "unit" part of unit testing.

Comment: Yes, that worked. Worked as in I can confirm that it's running multiple times.

This probably means that "Visual NUnit" have a weakness I guess. I'll be able to work around this problem while they fix ut with using the GUI tool provided from NUnit.

Comment: Cool -- I'm sure the Visual Nunit devs would appreciate a bug report if you have the time for it.

Comment: I agree. Posted the bug on sourceforge :) Thanks for the input

Comment: Can you post a link to your bug report.  I'd like to follow it.

Comment: @AndersLindas:  There's a comment here meant for you.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3539858&group_id=266536&atid=1134546